# PCB data trace lengths tolerable difference for high frequency

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, camera, high-speed, length-matching

I have to interface a camera to a controller using the DCMI protocol for my project. I have around 17 (data+control) lines which are used with the camera. The frequency of operation is about **10 MHz**.

I use EAGLE for my designs. However, while designing the PCB, I am not able to match all the lines from the connector to the controller.

It would be helpful to know the tolerance in length difference that is allowed while designing this PCB. Would a 2-3 cm difference in lines beget problems?

Answer (score 6):

I doubt it at 10Mhz, you could think of propagation delay, or the time it takes your signal to travel down your outer layer traces as around 150ps/inch.   At 10Mhz you're looking at a 100ns clock period.   From that you can see that a few cm will hardly make a difference for you.

Your concern about matching is really about making sure you meet your setup and hold time margins from your clock (or strobe) to  your data.  Even at an inch, or 2.54cm, difference that means your signal would only be +/- 150ps from your clock.  I'd say you'll be fine.